# Grafana throws HTTP Error Bad Gateway for Prometheus data source

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I have Grafana and Prometheus set up on my k8s cluster. Both were installed thru helm using https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable.
Both Grafana and Prometheus are set up thru k8s nginx ingress with my domian addresses.
When I try to set up the Prometheus as a data source in Grafana I get `HTTP Error Bad Gateway`. In the chrome console in Grafana page I see:

`http://grafana.domain.com/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query?query=1%2B1&time=1554043210.447`

`Grafana version: Grafana v6.0.0 (commit: 34a9a62)`

Grafana data source settings for Prometheus:
`URL: https://prometheus.mydomain.com:9090`

`Access: Server(Default)`

`Auth: 
Basic & TLS Client Auth`

What might be wrong and how to debug/fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In Grafana data source settings  for prometheus database  add prometheus service dns and service port. Like below

```
<prometheus service name>. Namespace. Svc. Cluster. Local:9090
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood. Both Grafana and Prometheus are in the namesapce=monitoring. In the services I see for Prometheus: prometheus-server, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-kube-state-metrics, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-pushgateway,prometheus-server. So it should look like: ```prometheus-server. monitoring. Svc. Cluster. Local:9090``` ?

Comment: Grafana doesn't allow me to save it if I have prometheus-server. monitoring. svc. cluster. local:9090 in the Http url field. Any idea?

Comment: and I see in the Prometheus that one resource is down:https://172.31.xx.xx:443/metrics Get https://172.31.xx.xx:443/metrics: context deadline exceeded. Might be it the reason? How to make it running?

Comment: prometheus runs on port 9090.

Comment: prometheus-server. monitoring. svc. cluster. local:9090 should work. share the datasource definition screenshot from grafana in the question. let me take a look.

Comment: prom is not able to scrape metrics from one of the service. that is not a problem. you can check that container. get into that pod and run curl -k localhost:443/metrics.

Answer (score 0):

if you are run Grafana and Prometheus on docker on your local machine and this will do for the datasource settings

Add host as {host.docker.internal} : {port}

example - http://{host.docker.internal}:9090

Comment: Please note that your post might be misread as a link-only answer (which risks being deleted). If what you show is meant as code then please format it accordingly and add an explanation. Adding an explanation is also the right way if you do indeed mean this to be a link (though I doubt it).

Answer (score -1):

When you are trying to add a data source, like Prometheus it is a little bit confusing because they are asking for the http, but you have to put your IP adress.

You just have to open CMD and write ipconfig /all and then look at the IPv4 Direction and then you will have your IP.

So the last part is going to Prometheus and in the URL you have to put:
http://{your_IP}:9090